# AEM 6.2 Targetting not working properly in Author instance

Tags: aem

In my Author instance when I am trying to create a Segment in Personalization-->Audiences-->Create-->Create ContextHub Segment, it is not populating the dropdown values as shown in the screen shot below. Earlier it was showing the drop downs default values pre-filled. Also, in preview mode it is not showing personas to select to verify Targetting.

[image]

Can anyone share if faced similar issue earlier?